# UIBarButtonItem not calling function in another class when tapped

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to move a big chunk of my code to another file; I believe I have done this, however, I'm having trouble calling a function.

I have two files:

`scannerBrain.swift`

```
var parentView = UIViewController()

func startScan(){
//The code I want to execute is here
}
```

`scannerViewController.swift`

```
let scanner = scannerBrain()
scanner.parentView = self
let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: scanner, action: #selector(scanner.startScan))
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
```

This compiles fine, except `startScan` is never called. I tried changing the `rightButton`'s target to `self`, but that caused a crash of an `unrecognised selector sent to instance`

Appreciate any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`scanner` should be class level property, otherwise it will be released. Something like this.

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    let scanner = scannerBrain()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scanner.parentView = self
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: scanner, action: #selector(scanner.startScan))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks bud! You helped a ton